# how to insert multiple rows in mysql database using laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I tried to store data in database using multiple rows by using the code as shown below but it doesn't work nor show me any error. When I click on the Submit button nothing happens. Please help me I'm new to laravel.

PR.blade.php:

```
               <form  action="addPR"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                    <div class="form-floating">
                     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="bg-light rounded h-100 p-4">    
            
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                            
                            <table class="table text-start align-middle table-bordered table-hover mb-0" >
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th >Item Name</th>
                                    <th >Description</th>
                                    <th >Quantity</th>
                                    <th >Remark</th>
                                    <th ><a class="btn btn-info addRow" id = "addRow"onclick="addRow()">+</a></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
            
                                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item_name" name="item_name[]" required=""></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description[]" required=""></td>
                                    <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="item_qty" name="item_qty[]" required=""></td>
                                    <td><input type="text"class="form-control" id="remark" name="remark[]"required="" ></td>
                                    <td><a href="#"class="btn btn-danger remove" id="remove">x</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                
                                
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                         </div>
                          <br><br>       
               <button type="button"class="btn btn-success" >Submit</button>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
           </form>
```

Javascript in PR.blade.php:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
   

        function addRow(){
            var tr=  '<tr>'+
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="item_name" name="item_name[]" required=""></td>'+
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description[]" required=""></td>'+
            '<td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="item_qty" name="item_qty[]" required=""></td>'+
            '<td><input type="text"class="form-control" id="remark" name="remark[]"required="" ></td>'+
            '<td><a href="#"class="btn btn-danger remove" id="remove">x</a></td>'+
        '</tr>';
        $('tbody').append(tr);
        }
     $(document).on('click', '#remove', function(){
        
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();

     });
        
   
 </script>
```

Route:

```
Route::post('addPR', [AdminController::class, 'addDataPR']);
```

Controller:

```
 public function addDataPR(Request $req)
{
   foreach($req->item_name as $key=>$insert){
    $savedata =[
    'item_name'   =>$req->item_name[$key],
    'description' =>$req->description[$key],
    'item_qty' =>$req->item_qty[$key],
    'remark' =>$req->remark[$key],
    ];
    return dd($key);
    DB::table('purchase__requests')->insert($savedata);
   }
     return redirect()->back();
   }
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you do a `dd($req->all())`in your controller, what does it show? I hope you left out the `return dd($key);`?

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question @OnkiHara. I tried to put dd($req->all()) and left the return dd($key); but still nothing happens.

Comment: can you place dd($request) above the foreach and post its result here

Comment: Placing dd($req->all()) above the foreach and my changing Submit button to          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="Submit" > the results I got is:                                                                                                                     ^ array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "EaHdrgDmeO3xUKzFDNXqaCeTtQerOUC3Tr8pUuHk"
  "item_name" => array:1 [▶]
  "description" => array:1 [▶]
  "item_qty" => array:1 [▶]
  "remark" => array:1 [▶]
  "submit" => "Submit"
]

Comment: Be careful about using "id" attributes that are not unique. They should exist only once per page

Answer (score 1):

Better practice is to rename your form fields as follows;

```html
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="item_name" name="items[][name]" required=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="items[][description]" required=""></td>
    <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="item_qty" name="items[][qty]" required=""></td>
    <td><input type="text"class="form-control" id="remark" name="items[][remark]"required="" ></td>
```

and then inserting into the database is much cleaner because you have an array of items, each of which has named keys;

```php
public function addDataPR(Request $req)
{
    // here you can validate as array

    foreach($req->items as $item){
        DB::table('purchase__requests')->insert([
        'item_name' => $item['name'],
        'description' =>$item['description'],
        'item_qty' =>$item['qty'],
        'remark' =>$item['remark']
        ]);
    }
     return redirect()->back();
}
```

This structure allows you to use array validation

```
    'items.*.name' => 'required|max:50',
```

etc

*dont forget to edit your html template row in the same way*